# why use annotation to extract point cut expression in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot AOP provide an annotation @Pointcut that can be useing to extract point cut expression, but I find that I can use a String variable do the same thing. Why we need an annotation, @Pointcut, to extract repeating code?

```java
//Extract point cut expression
    private final String pointCut = "execution(* com.steve.service.impl.DeptServiceImpl.*(..))";
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.steve.service.impl.DeptServiceImpl.*(..))")
    private void pointCut(){}
``


Expecting an explanation.
```